# How to add a button in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I´m confused with this whole "no CSS" thing, but I understand why it's beneficial. All I want to do is place a button in the middle of the screen but I don't understand how styling works in React yet. This is my code:

```
var tapSpeed = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Tap me as fast as you can!
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.button}>
        !
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFCCCC'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  button: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#ffffff',
    marginBottom: 7,
    border: 1px solid blue,
    borderRadius: 2px
  }
});
```

Comment: there were some errant semicolons and extra commas before the edit -- i assume those were just typos. if not you may want to look into that

Comment: It wasn't a typo, but thank you. However, I copy-pasted the edited code and the simulator is throwing an error (the screen is red). Any other idea?

Comment: ah the border should have quotes around it: `border: '1px solid blue',`

Comment: can you set the button margins to all 'auto'? (haven't played with react-native much)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand You cannot set button margins to auto. If you want buttons to stretch wrap them change the `lineItems` property value to `'stretch'` in the example provided.

Comment: Why doesn't this ship with a button!?!?!

Answer (score 36):

**Update:** use built-in [Button component](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html).

**Deprecated:**

Wrap your View into [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#content) for iOS and [TouchableNativeFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html#content) for Android.

```
var {
  Platform,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableNativeFeedback 
} = React;

var tapSpeed = React.createClass({
  buttonClicked: function() {
    console.log('button clicked');
  },
  render: function() {
    var TouchableElement = TouchableHighlight;
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
     TouchableElement = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    }
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Tap me as fast as you can!
      </Text>
      <TouchableElement
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={this.buttonClicked.bind(this)}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button!</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableElement>        
    </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: where to see the console.log() output?

Comment: @Chetan set debugging in chrome with long tap pn the screen, and open browser's console.

Comment: FYI, [the `TouchableNativeFeedback` doc says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html#content): `At the moment it only supports having a single View instance as a child node`. The `<Text>` must be wrapped in a `View`. Please edit your answer so people don't make the same mistake.

Comment: Augustin is right, the Text tag must be within a View tag like this "<View><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button!</Text></View>", or there will be runtime error "Invariant Violation: RawText Button! must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component".

Comment: thanks for the tips in the comments. please edit answer for android:     <TouchableElement
                    style={styles.button}>
                    <view>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Button!</Text>
                    </view>
                </TouchableElement>

Comment: On newer versions of react bind() is unnecessary, react gives this warning: `Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.`

Answer (score 28):

*You can use built in react-native Button element.*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Alert, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

class MainApp extends Component {

_onPress() {
  Alert.alert('on Press!');
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button onPress={this._onPress} title="Hello" color="#FFFFFF" accessibilityLabel="Tap on Me"/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#2E9298',
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 3
    },
    shadowRadius: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 0.25
  }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MainApp', () => MainApp);
```

[image]

Read More [Here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html).

Answer (score 25):

The [react-native-button](https://github.com/ide/react-native-button) package provides a button that is styled like a native button. Install it with `npm install react-native-button` and use it in your component like this:

```
var Button = require('react-native-button');

var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'blue'}}
        onPress={this._handlePress}>
        Press Me!
      </Button>
    );
  },

  _handlePress(event) {
    console.log('Pressed!');
  },
});
```

Comment: You should probably add `--save`, like this: `npm install react-native-button --save`.

Comment: not working... 
Got this error: Error: Requiring unknown module "react-native-button". 
but i have been installed the package before use it

Comment: @backslash112 Try restarting the packager.

Comment: This looks native on iOS, not on Android.

Comment: Works, but it doesn't appear to be possible to vertically center the text inside the button if the button is taller than the text. Cf. https://github.com/ide/react-native-button/issues/9. Any ideas?

Comment: Using TouchableHighlight you can center the text with   justifyContent: 'center'

Comment: what does accessibilityLabel does.. any idea !

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to achieve a touchable component/button to handle user's events.

- One is to use the built in `Button` Component. Check the docs here http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html
- Two use either `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableNativeFeedback` or `TouchableOpacity` or `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. Think of this as a way for you to convert different areas of your app to tappable(clickable) or a way for you to create a custom button.
  Each component here is different based on how it behaves once it's tapped by the user. Check the docs for more details. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html etc.

Concerning styling in react native you will need to understand flexbox layout. Check this css flexbox article all rules are applicable to react-native https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ except that you will have to capitalize the rules e.g `align-content` to `alignContent`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
  onPress={onPressLearnMore}
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
  barcodeAction = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('BarCodeScanner')
  }

  cleverTapAction = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('CleverTapApp')
  }
} 

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="Press Me"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="Press Me"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.alternativeLayoutButtonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="This looks great!"
          />
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="OK!"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    margin: 20
  },
  alternativeLayoutButtonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
var tapSpeed = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Tap me as fast as you can!
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text>!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFCCCC'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 7,
    border: 1px solid blue,
    borderRadius: 2px
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [react-native doc's](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/button.html#button) regarding the buttons

You have more than one way to add button in your application and styling it

You can use Button tag and it's have only one way styling by color attribute, it will appearing in IOS different than Android, or by putting button in view tag with style

`<View  style={style.buttonViewStyle}>
       <Button title="Facebook" color="blue" onPress={this.onFacebookPress} />
   </View>`

And check the TouchableOpacity and TouchableNativeFeedback tags

And take a lock on below link for more options to add custom buttons in your app

https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-action-button?search=button

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` element from `react-native` package does not provide built in styling feature. Ex. The "title" props will be in upper case by default. Hence, I've used an another package `react-native-elements` that provides nice features for Button element along with different styling options.

You can refer more details on [Button from `react-native-elements`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html)