# How to add a iOS Button to a react native component

Tags: ios, react-native

I try to create a simple interface to compare to a simple app built with xcode/swift. And even if i am impressed by react native i do not find a simple way to create a damn vanilla button. Did I miss something or is the button a different beast . Anyway I can't find a simple way to do it and will definitely appreciate some examples(i try to get the exact look and feel of an ios app , i try to be native !!!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a button in React Native?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872918/how-to-add-a-button-in-react-native)